# mezzanine 4.2.3 has requirement django<1.11,>=1.8, but you'll have django 2.0.2 which is incompatible

Tags: python, pip, command-prompt

```
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Py_Project\CBD Robotics\week5>pip install imagekit
Collecting imagekit
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/7c/a762c3902a1173cd9801
0ddc2ce588b5764220d47f09d801f5eab6b5bee4/imagekit-1.0.6.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: imagekit
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for imagekit ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\60\7a\6a\b6c
8af51341a51376cf1fe8a5b876086d84f2bc3683ee6b8c8
Successfully built imagekit
mezzanine 4.2.3 has requirement django<1.11,>=1.8, but you'll have django 2.0.2
which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: imagekit
Successfully installed imagekit-1.0.6

C:\Users\USER\Documents\Py_Project\CBD Robotics\week5>
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Py_Project\CBD Robotics\week5>pip3 install imagekit
Requirement already satisfied: imagekit in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-pack
ages (1.0.6)
mezzanine 4.2.3 has requirement django<1.11,>=1.8, but you'll have django 2.0.2
which is incompatible.
```

I am trying to install some libs but every time i want to install new libraries. I encountered this message from command-line

Comment: I think it says you need django 1.11

Comment: Why? because i am doing things which is not related to django

Comment: Here, it is written in their [documentation](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html#installation). Scroll a little down, and you'll see the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that this message is a warning, not an error, and that imagekit package has been properly installed in your current environment.

Now about the warning: it tells you that your current environment contains version 4.2.3 of mezzanine and version 2.0.2 of Django, which are not compatible (mezzanine 4.2.3 requires django 1.8 to 1.11). You mention that you're "doing things which is not related to django", well, why do you have django and mezzanine installed in this environment then ? If those are globals installs (outside a virtualenv) then you're doing it wrong, you should leave the global (system) env alone and use virtualenvs for your projects so you don't have broken dependencies issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Mezzanine 4.3.1 with Django 2.2 support** (until release Mezzanine v.5 will be ready)

you can use the following line in your requirements

`-e git+git://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine.git@9768b46f8377796d5d51d74db54589c9d3669a47#egg=Mezzanine  # feat: Add Django 2.2 compatability (#1956)`

or for pip
 `pip install -e git+git://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine.git@9768b46f8377796d5d51d74db54589c9d3669a47#egg=Mezzanine`

[related PR](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/pull/1956)